# How to create Grand Total in main report

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using *iReport 5.0.0*. I have some problem about create grand total. I have a *main report* that group by *field A* and send parameter to *subreport* that grouped by *field B*. However the main report and *subreport* have difference query. And in *subreport* it calculate the total and I pass the value to *main report* that I must calculate grand total in *Summary* band.

My Problem is: How can I calculate grand-total in *main report*? (I can pass the total value from *subreport* to *main report*)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: are you solved this problem, because i am also facing this problems

Comment: if you solve this problem,let me inform the solution please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have to create a total in your sub-report and Send it back to your main report. 
In your sub-report create a variable that calculates your subtotal total for the sub-report .
In your main-report create your variable that calculates your Subtotal for the main report,
Also create a variable to store the Subtotal value from your sub-report.

Now to pass the value back form the Sub-report to the main report,
in the properties of the sub-report object in the main report under **Return Values** click add to map the sub-report variable to the main report

Now you can either do the addition of main-report Subtotal + sub-report Subtotal in a new text field on in a new variable to get your Grand-total

Comment: Thank you for your advice Mike, I try for your suggestion but it's not work. $V{Grandtotal} in main report has property --> Variable Class = Double, Calculation = sum , Reset Type = Report, Variable expression = $V{Quantity} (that calculate the sum group in main report). Please help me again.

Comment: And I don't know why the first value of $V{GrandTltal} = null and when it sum the value it don't sum the last value. Example sum1 =1, sum2 =2, sum3 = 3 but the result is G_total1 = null, Gtotal2 = 1 ,and Gtotal3 = 3. Please help me.

Comment: your jrxml would help but,  the $V{Grandtotal} calculation = Nothing and the expression should be something like $V{Quantity} + $V{SubQuantity}.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Mike. I found the  solution here http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522333/subreport-return-value-null . Thank you for your help again.